# Join select queries on an id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I have three tables that `SELECT` from and I'd need to join the results.

It feels like this should be a rather easy task but I struggle with the syntax.

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

What I came up with so far is..

- `TableA` has `id` (int), `name` (varchar), `comment` (varchar) and `extra` (varchar).
- `TableB` has `id` (int) and `char` (varchar)
- `TableC` has `eid` (int) and `info` (varchar).

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    b.count, a.id, a.name, a.comment 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM TableA a
     WHERE id + 100 IN (SELECT distinct(eid)
                        FROM TableC
                        WHERE NOT eid IS NULL)
    )
JOIN
   (SELECT 
        char, count(*) AS count 
    FROM TableB b sel 
    GROUP BY char) on a.id + 100 = b.char
```

What I'd like to have is the output of the top select (`TableA`) with the count of `TableB` where `a.id+100` is `b.char`

Excuse my amateur-ish sql..

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this should work...

We're checking that `TableA.id+100` is in `TableC.eid` and then counting the number of times `TableA.id+100` appears as `TableB.char`.

It's always good to create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) though so that others can easily pick up your schema and code to debug.

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name,
  a.comment,
  COUNT(b.char) AS count
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
  ON a.id+100 = b.char
INNER JOIN TableC 
  ON a.id+100 = c.eid
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.comment;
```

As Aaron Bertrand pointed out below, using `EXISTS` would help to eliminate double counting on where duplicate `eid`s appear in  `TableC`.

```
SELECT
      a.id,
      a.name,
      a.comment,
      COUNT(b.char) AS count
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
  ON a.id+100 = b.char
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableC where eid = a.id+100)
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.comment;
```